# What this phrase trying to say?

Tags: sentence-meaning, translation

Could anyone please help me with this, I dont get the meaning, why he said that is satisfying and also crushing? And also what is the meaning of I read a good deal?  Btw gradually he become a poet

- It was my last year. I’d wanted to be a football player very much,
  and got my letter but didn’t make the team. Well, that was **satisfying
  but crushing too**. **I read a good deal**, but had never written. So this
  was a recoil from that. Then I had some luck in that Richard Eberhart
  was teaching there.

Comment: **I guess**, the letter was satisfying, probably the invitation to take part in test training which disappointingly didn't result in admission to the team that he applied to. The *reading a good deal* seems to be unrelated to the football playing, but maybe he wrote an application letter to the team. He admits he never had written, so I wouldn't expect this text to be very well written or perfectly understandable.

Comment: *to read a good deal* means to read a lot of texts and "good" implies the reading was worth his time, although the phrase is used inflationary, loosing the aspect of good value.

Comment: @Hectorvon exactly you're right, in the text, before this part he saying about spend some time on reading books and here saying that it was worth. But I dont get the conection beween the letter and it was satisfaying and also crushing

Comment: The letter was satisfying. Later he was rejected, which was crushing.

Answer (score 1):

In US high schools it is common for to award "letters", a patch bearing the school monogram, to participants in school activities such as sports teams or the band or orchestra.

Every school and organization within the school has its own criteria for awarding letters. In this passage the writer probably earned his letter for commitment and effort—perhaps on the practice squad. So it was satisfying to earn the letter, even though it was crushing not to be selected for the team.

It's traditional to wear the letter on a sweater or jacket of the school colors, like these:

[image][image]